# Select HTML item using VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from this  [website](https://www.castorama.ru/building-materials/building-dry-materials-and-primers) and I need to select value from picture  (in this case "Москва, Новорязанское ш."):

[image: screen]

I am having trouble identifying the correct "class" to use and also not sure of which functions can be leveraged to target the specific values I'm trying to keep. 
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Code that I have:

```
Public Sub Selected()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "https://www.castorama.ru/building-materials/building-dry-materials-and-primers"
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    .document.getElementsByClassName("store-switcher__current-store-i").querySelector("[shop='Воронеж']").Click

    Stop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: my guidance is to make your life easier and not use VBA for a web scraping task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the HTML of the page you will see each shop has its own `data-id` attribute value. You can select and click the appropriate shop name node by the value of this attribute:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MakeShopSelection()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 "https://www.castorama.ru/building-materials/building-dry-materials-and-primers"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("[data-id='36']").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop

        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

---

The following will list the ids for you:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ListIds()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, idDict As Object, shopNames As Object

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set idDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ie
        .Visible = True

        .navigate2 "https://www.castorama.ru/building-materials/building-dry-materials-and-primers"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim i As Long

        With .document
            Set shopNames = .querySelectorAll(".shop__name")

            For i = 0 To shopNames.Length - 1
                idDict(Trim$(shopNames.Item(i).innertext)) = shopNames.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id")
            Next
        End With

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(idDict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(idDict.keys)
            .Cells(1, 2).Resize(idDict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(idDict.items)
        End With

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```